# gvim warning: LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING

Tags: vim, gvim

In gvim, if I do `gvim .` it uses netrw to show directory structure. Then if I open a file and then, without editting, do `:E` and then open the file again I get,

`LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.`

I haven't noticed any effect in functionality of gvim, it just annoying to see the warning, how can I fix this or less preferably hide the error?

Answer (score 0):

This workaround works for me (after a quick test)

```
function gvim () {
    `which gvim` $* &> /dev/null
}
```